# how to execute multiple count query in php

Tags: php, mysql, count

I executed 4 count queries from one table. but I am getting the same output from all the queries. but the actual value is different in the table.

Here is my table.

```
ID ||  notify_type     ||  status
__________________________________________

1  || resume_uploaded  ||    1
```

Here are my queries:

```
$notify_query1 = "select count(*) from notify where status = 1 and notify_type = 'resume_uploaded'";
$row1 = mysqli_query($db_manager->connection,$notify_query1);
$rcount = mysqli_num_rows($row1);

$notify_query2 = "select count(*) from notify where status = 1 and  notify_type = 'detail_filled'";
$row2 = mysqli_query($db_manager->connection,$notify_query2);
$dcount = mysqli_num_rows($row2);

$notify_query3 = "select count(*) from notify where status = 1 and notify_type = 'job_detailed'";
$row3 = mysqli_query($db_manager->connection,$notify_query3);
$jcount = mysqli_num_rows($row3);

$notify_query4 = "select count(*) from notify where status = 1 and notify_type = 'msg_sent'";
$row4 = mysqli_query($db_manager->connection,$notify_query4);
$mcount = mysqli_num_rows($row4);
```

I am getting output  *1* from all the four queries:
Please help me.

Comment: Don't get `num_row`, `fetch` the returned row then get the count with `$row["count(*)"]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) instead `mysqli_num_rows()`.

```
$result = $db->query("select count(*) from notify where status = 1 and notify_type = 'resume_uploaded'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo 'No of count: '. $row[0];
```